# Group 2 columns to categories based on the column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
                   'Position': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '0', '1', '2', '3', '0', '1', '2', '0', '1', '2'],
                   'Brand': ['Mazda', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'Dodge', 'Mazda', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat']
                   })
```

I want to group the `position` and `brand` together to make a category.

The output would look like this:

```
ID  Group
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   3
```

Because group 1 is:

```
0 Mazda
1 BMW
2 Ford
3 Fiat
4 Dodge
```

And  `c` = `d` because they both have the same care makers in the same order so the group is the same - 3:

```
0 BMW
1 Ford
2 Fiat
```

If `d` would have different order defined by the column `position` it would be a different category:

```
0 Fiat
1 BWM
2 Ford
```

How could I achieve the output as defined in the second code block?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can distinguish same 3 first rows per groups with filter by `head` and convert to tuples and then use [`Series.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html):

```
s = (df.groupby(['ID'], sort=False)['Position','Brand']
       .apply(lambda x: tuple(x.head(3).values.ravel())))

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':s.index, 'Cat':pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1})
print (df)
  ID  Cat
0  a    1
1  b    1
2  c    2
3  d    2
```

Comment: Hi and thank you @jezrael that worked! Maybe a small adjustment could be made if I only wanted to group by the first 3 brands rather than the full list under the same `ID`? For example `Mazda, Ford, Fiat` would be in the same group as `Mazda, Ford, Fiat, BMW` because the first three items are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, you are a true genius in pandas.